# How to set the text in to Spinner using Android

Tags: android

How to set the text into Spinner using Android.

**Edittext**

```
 ed1 = findViewById(R.id.pname);
```

**spinner**

```
spinner = findViewById(R.id.catid);
```

**Edit text i will able to set the text
but spinner i couldn't set the text**

```
String t1 = i.getStringExtra("product").toString();

String t2 = i.getStringExtra("category").toString();

ed1.setText(t1);
spinner.setSelected(t2.toString()); `
```

i attached error below along the screen shot image below
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nn871.jpg]

Comment: You can't directly select an item in a spinner. You need to use an adapter to populate your spinner

Comment: You can't just add a string value  to setSelected cause it's expecting  a boolean value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the setSelected(bool) indicates the selection state of the spinner, it accepts a boolean as parameters and you have tried to put a string, it's so normal to get this error.

You can use spinner.setSelection(int) and enter the position of the item that you want to select. To get your item's position you can use the spinner's adapter by adapter.getPosition("yourValue")

this was an example:

```
int position = adapter.getPosition("category");
spinner.setSelection(position);
```

Comment: Intent i = getIntent();
    String t3 = i.getStringExtra("category").toString(); how get the value from the Intend and loop it

Answer (score 2):

The `spinner.setSelected()` doesn't require a `String` but a `boolean`  . So try this code to set text to spinner

```
public void setSpinText(Spinner spinner, String text){
    for(int i= 0; i < spinner.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {
        if(spin.getAdapter().getItem(i).toString().contains(text)) {
            spinner.setSelection(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you go like this :

```
String t1 = i.getStringExtra("product").toString();

 String t2 = i.getStringExtra("category").toString();

 ed1.setText(t1);
 setSpinText(spinner,t2);
```

Comment: data pass one activity to another  i.putExtra("category", stu.category); this send to activity 2 set like this String t2 = i.getStringExtra("category").toString(); then how to loop it please help me

Comment: if  you want to loop a string do this : 
`for (int i = 0; i < yourString.length(); i++){}`

Comment: I made an eddit to the answer

Comment: sir i wrote i like this     for (int ii = 0; ii < t2.length(); ii++){
            spinner.setSelection(ii);
        }   but not working