# Spinner item selection problem with TextView

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a table in `Mysql` database with some plugs, and i added all the plugs to spinner from database.I want to retreive the data according to spinner selection.I am facing a problem that there is two records in database for `plug1`,when i selected `plug1` its retreiving properly,when i selected `plug2` in spinner its retreiving  another record of `plug1`. I have used on-selected item position that is why it is taking position wise order.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".DashboardActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background=" #dfe3e7"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_dashboard">


    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinnerDevices"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/spinner"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:overlapAnchor="false"></Spinner>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="20dp">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:text="ON/OFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"/>

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/on"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:checkable="true"

            android:padding="5dp" />

    </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"

       >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background=" #1c2833"
            android:padding="8dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:background="@drawable/image1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/device1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/imageView1"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:fontFamily="serif"
                android:text="TEMPERATURE"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/meter1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/device1"
                android:fontFamily="serif"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:textColor="#ff6861"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background=" #1c2833"
                android:padding="7dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/image2"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/device2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:fontFamily="serif"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:text="CURRENT"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/meter2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/device2"
                    android:fontFamily="serif"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                    android:textColor="#ff6861"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_margin="1dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background=" #1c2833"
                android:padding="7dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/image3"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/device3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/imageView3"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:fontFamily="serif"
                    android:text="VOLTAGE"
                   android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/meter3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/device3"
                    android:fontFamily="serif"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:textColor="#ff6861"
                    />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>>
</LinearLayout
```

**JAVA**

```
package com.example.sp;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class DashboardActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements  Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener , NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private static final String TAG = "DashboardActivity";
    private String URLstring = "http://192.168.0.108/Smart/getdata.php";
    public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "data";
    public static final String EmployeeNamearray = "plugno";
    private TextView textView;
    String line=null;
    private ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    private JSONArray data;
    private JSONArray result;
    private ArrayList<String> students;
    private final int jsoncode = 1;
    private Spinner spinner;
    String status="";
    private TextView textViewName, textViewCourse, textViewSession;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.greeting_text_view);
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerDevices);
        names = new ArrayList<String>();
        students = new ArrayList<String>();
        getdata();
        getData();
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        textViewName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.meter1);
        textViewCourse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.meter2);
        textViewSession = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.meter3);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        Switch s = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.on);

        s.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    Toast.makeText(DashboardActivity.this, "switch is on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(DashboardActivity.this, "switch is off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }
    private void getData() {
        //Creating a string request
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Config.DATA_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        JSONObject j = null;
                        try {
                            //Parsing the fetched Json String to JSON Object
                            j = new JSONObject(response);

                            //Storing the Array of JSON String to our JSON Array
                            result = j.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);

                            //Calling method getStudents to get the students from the JSON Array
                            getStudents(result);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });

        //Creating a request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private void getStudents(JSONArray j) {
        //Traversing through all the items in the json array
        for (int i = 0; i < j.length(); i++) {
            try {
                //Getting json object
                JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);
if(json.getString("plugno").equals("plugno")){
    students.add(json.getString(Config.TAG_PLUGNO));
}
                //Adding the name of the student to array list

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        //Setting adapter to show the items in the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(DashboardActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, students));
        spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(DashboardActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, names));
    }

    //Method to get student name of a particular position
    private String getName(int position) {
        String name = "";
        try {
            //Getting object of given index
            JSONObject json = result.getJSONObject(position);

            //Fetching name from that object
            name = json.getString(Config.TAG_TEMPERATURE);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Returning the name
        return name;
    }

    //Doing the same with this method as we did with getName()
    private String getCourse(int position) {
        String course = "";
        try {
            JSONObject json = result.getJSONObject(position);
            course = json.getString(Config.TAG_CURRENT);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return course;
    }

    //Doing the same with this method as we did with getName()
    private String getSession(int position) {
        String session = "";
        try {
            JSONObject json = result.getJSONObject(position);
            session = json.getString(Config.TAG_VOLTAGE);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return session;
    }


    //this method will execute when we pic an item from the spinner
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //Setting the values to textviews for a selected item

    }

    //When no item is selected this method would execute
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        textViewName.setText("");
        textViewCourse.setText("");
        textViewSession.setText("");
    }


    private void getdata() {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest("http://192.168.0.108/Smart/getdata.php",
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        JSONObject j = null;
                        try {
                            j = new JSONObject(response);
                           data = j.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);
                            empdetails(data);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }


    private void empdetails(JSONArray j) {

        for (int i = 0; i < j.length(); i++) {
            try {
                JSONObject json = j.getJSONObject(i);
                names.add(json.getString(EmployeeNamearray));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        // arrayList.add(0,"Select Employee");

        spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(DashboardActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,names));
        spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(DashboardActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, students));
    }
    //Method to get student name of a particular position+





    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddPlugActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            // Handle the camera action


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;

        }



        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55849771/how-to-set-the-text-in-to-spinner-using-android/55849832#55849832

Answer (score 2):

In this method add like this

```
//this method will execute when we pic an item from the spinner
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

     yourlist.get(position);
    }
```

Let me know if it works for you .

Comment: it was not working

Comment: what error are you getting

Comment: your are replacing yourList with?

Comment: iam replacing with my array list which was recieving from database

Comment: can u check once the below code i did exact the same way